Change Contact Email in Azure DevOps Profile
in my Azure DevOps account, I go to Profile - I change the contact Email and it shows status "Pending" I go to my mailbox to the confirmation email, but when I press confirm I see the following error:
"We encountered an error trying to finalize the verification of your email address. If you feel you have reached this page in error please sign out of the service and try again later. Error details: *The preferred email verification failed, please try again later."
I tried the solution from this link but it does not work , I see the same Error:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/preferred-email-confirmation-fail/624610
So if I copy and open the confirm URL in a private window of the browser to see if the preferred Email confirmation still is failed, the error still shows up.

I confirm the contact email can be changed successfully now, please check the details below, thanks.

I can reproduce the same error. It could be a service incident currently. It's recommended to try again after some time, suggest tomorrow.

Edit: I confirm the contact email is successfully changed today. If you still encounter the error, please change to another new contact email, then change again to your target email.


still same error by me, tried also from private

On the error page, please try to logout -> close all browsers -> launch an inPrivate window -> try to change contact email with another email -> copy the confirm email to private window to complete -> change again to your target email till confirmation done.

@MyADOObsession, you can follow the step above to have a check, let me know if you have queries.

Glad to know it works!  Happy day!
